# mitmproxy transparent proxy over mikrotik not working

Tags: transparent, mitmproxy

I've setup transparent proxy using mitmproxy on kali linux.
I followed the instruction on https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/howto-transparent/ to setup on linux.
And mikrotik also has been setup for NAT like this one :
/ip firewall nat
add action=dst-nat chain=dstnat dst-port=80,443 protocol=tcp src-address=192.168.10.25 to-addresses=192.168.10.24

where 192.168.10.24 is kali linux running mitmproxy
192.168.10.25 is the windows 7 client which using the transparent proxy

i started it on kali linux with
mitmproxy -p 3129 --mode transparent --showhost

when i'm browse to such url website i found some errors like this

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>502 Bad Gateway</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1>
  <p>ProtocolException(&#x27;Server connection to (\&#x27;192.168.10.24\&#x27;, 80) failed: Error connecting to &quot;192.168.10.24&quot;: [Errno 24] Too many open
files&#x27;)</p>
</body>
</html>
```

can anyone solve this problem ?
thanks before..